# Taylor Series Difference between exp(-x) and exp(+x)

Tags: c++, iteration, rounding, series, function-approximation

I'm trying to write a program which calculates the Taylor series of exp(-x) and exp(x) up to 200 iterations, for large x. (exp(x)=1+x+x^2/2+...).

My program is really simple, and it seems like it should work perfectly.  However it diverges for exp(-x), but converges just fine for exp(+x). Here is my code so far:

```
long double x = 100.0, sum = 1.0, last = 1.0;

for(int i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
        last *= x / i;    //multiply the last term in the series from the previous term by x/n
        sum += last; //add this new last term to the sum
    }
cout << "exp(+x) = " << sum << endl;

x = -100.0; //redo but now letting x<0
sum = 1.0;
last = 1.0;

for(int i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
            last *= x / i;
            sum += last;
        }
    cout << "exp(-x) = " << sum << endl;
```

And when I run it, I get the following output:

```
exp(+x) = 2.68811691354e+43 
exp(-x) = -8.42078025179e+24
```

When the actual values are:

```
exp(+x) = 2.68811714182e+43 
exp(-x) = 3.72007597602e-44
```

As you can see, it works just fine for the positive calculation, but not negative. Does anyone have any ideas on why rounding errors could go so wrong by just adding a negative on every other term? Also, is there anything I could implement to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "fine" in "it works fine for the positive calculation". In absolute terms, the result for the positive exponential is actually further from the real answer than for the negative exponential! |2.68811691354e+43 - 2.68811714182e+43| = 2.2828e+36 for e^100 versus |-8.42078025179e+24 - 3.72007597602e-44| = 8.42078e+24 for e^-100

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, by fine I meant in terms of relative error, which is ~0.00000001 for the positive exponential, and ~10^68 for the negative exponent :(

Comment: Is this just for interest, or do you have an application where you can use double-precision numbers but can't use the standard library exp() ?

Comment: @RoryYorke This is just for interest, I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm trying to get a handle on precision and rounding errors.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this actually has anything to do with floating point approximation error, I think there is another more significant source of error.

As you say yourself, your method is really simple. You are taking a taylor series approximation at `x=0` to this function, and then evaluating it at `x=-100`.

How accurate did you actually expect this method to be and why?

At a high level, you should only expect your method to be accurate in a narrow region near `x=0`. Taylor's approximation theorem tells you that e.g. if you take `N` terms of the series around `x=0`, your approximation will be accurate to `O(|x|)^(N+1)` at least. So if you take 200 terms, you should be accurate to e.g. within `10^(-60)` or so in the range `[-0.5, 0.5]`. But at `x=100` Taylor's theorem only gives you a pretty terrible bound.

Conceptually, you know that `e^{-x}` tends to zero as `x` goes to minus infinity. But your approximation function is a polynomial of a fixed degree, and any non-constant polynomial tends to either plus infinity or minus infinity asymptotically. So the relative error must be unbounded if you consider the whole range of possible values of `x`.

So in short I think you should rethink your approach. One thing you might consider is, only use the Taylor series method for `x` values satisfying `-0.5f <= x <= 0.5f`. And for any `x` greater than `0.5f`, you try dividing `x` by two and calling the function recursively, then squaring the result. Or something like this.

For best results you should probably use an established method.

Edit:

I decided to write some code to see how well my idea actually works. It appears to match perfectly with the C library implementation across the range `x = -10000` to `x = 10000` at least to as many bits of precision as I am displaying. :)

Note also that my method is accurate even for values of `x` greater than 100, where the Taylor Series method actually loses accuracy on the positive end as well.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

long double taylor_series(long double x)
{
    long double sum = 1.0, last = 1.0;

    for(int i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
            last *= x / i;    //multiply the last term in the series from the previous term by x/n
            sum += last; //add this new last term to the sum
    }

    return sum;
}

long double hybrid(long double x)
{
    long double temp;
    if (-0.5 <= x && x <= 0.5) {
        return taylor_series(x);
    } else {
        temp = hybrid(x / 2);
        return (temp * temp);
    }
}

long double true_value(long double x) {
    return expl(x);
}

void output_samples(long double x) {
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\ttaylor series = " << taylor_series(x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\thybrid method = " << hybrid(x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\tlibrary = " << true_value(x) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    output_samples(-10000);
    output_samples(-1000);
    output_samples(-100);
    output_samples(-10);
    output_samples(-1);
    output_samples(-0.1);
    output_samples(0);
    output_samples(0.1);
    output_samples(1);
    output_samples(10);
    output_samples(100);
    output_samples(1000);
    output_samples(10000);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./main 
x = -10000
    taylor series = -2.48647e+423
    hybrid method = 1.13548e-4343
    library = 1.13548e-4343
x = -1000
    taylor series = -2.11476e+224
    hybrid method = 5.07596e-435
    library = 5.07596e-435
x = -100
    taylor series = -8.49406e+24
    hybrid method = 3.72008e-44
    library = 3.72008e-44
x = -10
    taylor series = 4.53999e-05
    hybrid method = 4.53999e-05
    library = 4.53999e-05
x = -1
    taylor series = 0.367879
    hybrid method = 0.367879
    library = 0.367879
x = -0.1
    taylor series = 0.904837
    hybrid method = 0.904837
    library = 0.904837
x = 0
    taylor series = 1
    hybrid method = 1
    library = 1
x = 0.1
    taylor series = 1.10517
    hybrid method = 1.10517
    library = 1.10517
x = 1
    taylor series = 2.71828
    hybrid method = 2.71828
    library = 2.71828
x = 10
    taylor series = 22026.5
    hybrid method = 22026.5
    library = 22026.5
x = 100
    taylor series = 2.68812e+43
    hybrid method = 2.68812e+43
    library = 2.68812e+43
x = 1000
    taylor series = 3.16501e+224
    hybrid method = 1.97007e+434
    library = 1.97007e+434
x = 10000
    taylor series = 2.58744e+423
    hybrid method = 8.80682e+4342
    library = 8.80682e+4342
```

Edit:

For who is interested:

There was some question raised in the comments about how significant the floating point errors are in the original program. My original assumption was that they were negligible -- I did a test to see if that's true or not. It turns out that's not true, and there is significant floating point error going on, but that even without the floating point errors there are significant errors being introduced just by the taylor series alone. The true value of the taylor series at 200 terms at `x=-100` seems to be near to `-10^{24}`, not `10^{-44}`. I checked this using `boost::multiprecision::cpp_rational`, which is an arbitrary precision rational type built on their arbitrary precision integer type.

Output:

```
x = -100
    taylor series (double) = -8.49406e+24
                (rational) = -18893676108550916857809762858135399218622904499152741157985438973568808515840901824148153378967545615159911801257288730703818783811465589393308637433853828075746484162303774416145637877964256819225743503057927703756503421797985867950089388433370741907279634245166982027749118060939789786116368342096247737/2232616279628214542925453719111453368125414939204152540389632950466163724817295723266374721466940218188641069650613086131881282494641669993119717482562506576264729344137595063634080983904636687834775755173984034571100264999493261311453647876869630211032375288916556801211263293563
                           = -8.46257e+24
    library                = 3.72008e-44
x = 100
    taylor series (double) = 2.68812e+43
                (rational) = 36451035284924577938246208798747009164319474757880246359883694555113407009453436064573518999387789077985197279221655719227002367495061633272603038249747260895707250896595889294145309676586627989388740458641362406969609459453916777341749316070359589697827702813520519796940239276744754778199440304584107317957027129587503199/1356006206645357299077422810994072904566969809700681604285727988319939931024001696953196916719184549697395496290863162742676361760549235149195411231740418104602504325580502523311497039304043141691060121240640609954226541318710631103275528465092597490136227936213123455950399178299
                           = 2.68812e+43
    library                = 2.68812e+43
```

Code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_rational rational;

// Taylor series of exp

template <typename T>
T taylor_series(const T x) {
    T sum = 1, last = 1;

    for (uint i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
        last = last * (x / i);
        sum = sum + last;
    }
    return sum;
}

void sample(const int x) {
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    long double e1 = taylor_series(static_cast<long double>(x));
    std::cout << "\ttaylor series (double) = " << e1 << std::endl;
    rational e2 = taylor_series(static_cast<rational>(x));
    std::cout << "\t            (rational) = " << e2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t                       = " << static_cast<long double>(e2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\tlibrary                = " << expl(static_cast<long double>(x)) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    sample(-100);
    sample(100);
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This is extremely helpful, I really appreciate this very thoughtful/insightful answer.  I really like that hybrid method.

Comment: This is a great answer, except for the first paragraph.  Some of the summands are (much!) greater in absolute value than 1, and the error is due to round-off error (as stated by rickandross http://stackoverflow.com/a/32365257/1008142 )

Comment: @RoryYorke: Thanks for this comment, I have edited my answer. I did some investigation of how significant the floating point error is here, now attached to answer. There is some significant floating point error taking place, but I think it's fair to say that it is not the primary source of error here.

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor polynomials probably isn't a great idea for this; see http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/152.php for a great article on using Chebyshev polynomials for function approximation.

rickandross pointed out the source of the error in this case, namely that the Taylor expansion for exp(-100) involves differences of large values.

There's a simple modification to the Taylor attempt that get reasonable answers for the few test cases I tried, namely using the fact that exp(-x) = 1/exp(x).  This programme:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double texp(double x)
{
  double last=1.0;
  double sum=1.0;
  if(x<0)
    return 1/texp(-x);

  for(int i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
    last *= x / i;
    sum += last;
  }

  return sum;
}

void test_texp(double x)
{
  double te=texp(x);
  double e=std::exp(x);
  double err=te-e;
  double rerr=(te-e)/e;
  std::cout << "x=" << x 
            << "\ttexp(x)=" << te 
            << "\texp(x)=" << e 
            << "\terr=" << err
            << "\trerr=" << rerr
            << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  test_texp(0);
  test_texp(1);
  test_texp(-1);
  test_texp(100);
  test_texp(-100);
}
```

gives this output (note that double precision is around 2e-16):

```
x=0 texp(x)=1   exp(x)=1    err=0   rerr=0
x=1 texp(x)=2.71828 exp(x)=2.71828  err=4.44089e-16 rerr=1.63371e-16
x=-1    texp(x)=0.367879    exp(x)=0.367879 err=-5.55112e-17    rerr=-1.50895e-16
x=100   texp(x)=2.68812e+43 exp(x)=2.68812e+43  err=1.48553e+28 rerr=5.52628e-16
x=-100  texp(x)=3.72008e-44 exp(x)=3.72008e-44  err=-2.48921e-59    rerr=-6.69128e-16
```